# login authentication zend framework

Tags: php, authentication, zend-framework, frameworks, zend-framework2

I'm new with the zend framework 2. I have to make a login system with the plugin authentication from zend framework. i found many solutions to do this, but mine is still not working. 
i'm probably doing something wrong, but i don't see my problem.
Will someone please help me with this?

code of my form LoginForm.php:

```
<?php

namespace System\Form;

use Zend\Form\Form;

class Login extends Zend_Form
{
    public function init()
    {
        $this->setMethod('post');

        $this->addElement(
            'text', 'email', array(
            'label' => 'Email:',
            'required' => true,
            'filters'    => array('StringTrim'),
        ));

        $this->addElement('password', 'password', array(
            'label' => 'Password:',
            'required' => true,
        ));

        $this->addElement('submit', 'submit', array(
            'ignore'   => true,
            'label'    => 'Login',
        ));

    }
}
```

Code InlogController.php :

```
<?php

namespace System\Controller;

use Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController;
use Zend\View\Model\ViewModel;
use System\Form\Login;

class InlogController extends AbstractActionController
{
    public function loginAction()
    {
        $db = $this->_getParam('fms');

        $loginForm = new Login();

        if ($loginForm->isValid($_POST)) {

            $adapter = new Zend_Auth_Adapter_DbTable(
                $db,
                'user_name',
                'user_email',
                'user_password'
            );

            $adapter->setIdentity($loginForm->getValue('user_email'));
            $adapter->setCredential($loginForm->getValue('user_password'));

            $auth   = Zend_Auth::getInstance();
            $result = $auth->authenticate($adapter);

            if ($result->isValid()) {
                $this->_helper->FlashMessenger('Successful Login');
                $this->_redirect('/');
                return;
            }

        }

        $this->view->loginForm = $loginForm;

    }

}
```

Code index.phtml :

```
<?php

$title = "Login to vote";
$this->headTitle($title);
?>

    <h1><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($title); ?></h1>

<?php
$this->form->setAction($this->url());
echo $this->form;
```

This is the error
Fatal error: Call to a member function setAction() on a non-object in /mnt/hgfs/Sites/fms/module/System/view/system/inlog/index.phtml on line 10

Comment: Thank you i don't get the error anymore. But do i have to define Zend_Auth_Adapter_DbTable' somewhere in the Controller ? Because it's now giving me a warning that he can't find it. Do i have to make a class Zend_Auth_Adapter_DbTable'? i'm sorry for all my questions. Thanks in advance

Comment: You have a strange mix of ZF1 and ZF2 code here. Are you following a tutorial that might be for a different version?

Comment: I guess that's the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Please try with this:

## In Module.php

```
public function getServiceConfig()
{
    return array(
        'factories' => array(
            // some other service config setup,
            'AuthService' => function($sm) {
                $dbAdapter           = $sm->get('Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter');
                $dbTableAuthAdapter  = new DbTableAuthAdapter($dbAdapter,
                                            'users','email','password', '?');

                $authService = new AuthenticationService();
                $authService->setAdapter($dbTableAuthAdapter);
                $authService->setStorage($sm->get('Application\Model\MyAuthStorage')); // this is for session storage and optional for you

                return $authService;
            },
            // some other service config setup
        )
    );
}
```

## In Controller

```
public function getAuthService()
{
    if (! $this->authservice) {
        $this->authservice = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('AuthService');
    }

    return $this->authservice;
}
```

## While Authenticating

```
public function authenticateAction()
{
    // code to get Postdata from login FORM

    $this->getAuthService()->getAdapter()
                           ->setIdentity($postData['email'])
                           ->setCredential($postData['password']);
    $result = $this->getAuthService()->authenticate();

    if ($result->isValid()) {
        // successful logged in
    }
}
```

## EDIT

```
namespace Application\Model;

use Zend\Authentication\Storage;

class MyAuthStorage extends Storage\Session
{
    /**
     * Set remember me option
     * save the details in session
     *
     * @param <Int> $rememberMe default = 0
     * 
     * @return <Void>
     */
    public function setRememberMe($rememberMe = 0, $time = 1209600)
    {
        if ($rememberMe == 1) {
            $this->session->getManager()->rememberMe($time);
        }
    }

    /**
     * forget me
     * clear the session storage value
     *
     * @param <Void>
     *
     * @return <Void>
     */
    public function forgetMe()
    {
       $this->session->getManager()->forgetMe();
    }
}
```

## In Module.php

```
public function getServiceConfig()
{
    return array(
        'factories' => array(
            // some other service config setup,
            'Application\Model\MyAuthStorage' => function($sm){
                return new \Application\Model\MyAuthStorage('xyz');
            },
            'AuthService' => function($sm) {
                $dbAdapter           = $sm->get('Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter');
                $dbTableAuthAdapter  = new DbTableAuthAdapter($dbAdapter,
                                            'users','email','password', '?');

                $authService = new AuthenticationService();
                $authService->setAdapter($dbTableAuthAdapter);
                $authService->setStorage($sm->get('Application\Model\MyAuthStorage')); // this is for session storage and optional for you

                return $authService;
            },
            // some other service config setup
        )
    );
}
```

I think this one will help you.

## UPDATE (2nd update)

You need to include Zend_Auth_Adapter_DbTable like the below in Module.php file:

```
use Zend\Mvc\ModuleRouteListener, Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent, Application\Model\IndexTable,
    Zend\Db\ResultSet\ResultSet, Zend\Db\TableGateway\TableGateway,
    Zend\Authentication\AuthenticationService,
    Zend\Authentication\Adapter\DbTable as DbTableAuthAdapter;
```

Comment: hi, i see that i need this : authService->setStorage($sm->get('Application\Model\MyAuthStorage'));, but what do i have to put in MyAuthStorage? Sorry, i'm new to this all.

Comment: Thank you i don't get the error anymore. But do i have to define Zend_Auth_Adapter_DbTable' somewhere in the Controller ? Because it's now giving me a warning that he can't find it. Do i have to make a class Zend_Auth_Adapter_DbTable'? i'm sorry for all my questions. Thanks in advance

Comment: @KimberlyGS, I added the code for how to include Zend_Auth_Adapter_DbTable in Module.php file.

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
$adapter->setIdentity($loginForm->getValue('user_email'));
$adapter->setCredential($loginForm->getValue('user_password'));
```

By this, You must use right names of form elements to get its value:

```
$adapter->setIdentity($loginForm->getValue('email'));
$adapter->setCredential($loginForm->getValue('password'));
```

And in the view file change the form var name just as you had defined in the controller:

```
$this->loginForm->setAction(...);
```

Comment: I changed it, but I'm still getting this error : Fatal error: Call to a member function setAction() on a non-object in /mnt/hgfs/Sites/fms/module/System/view/system/inlog/index.phtml on line 10

Comment: And in the view file change the form var name just as you had defined in the controller:

$this->loginForm->setAction(...);